# How to modify Iterator on the fly without mutable variables?

Tags: scala, iterator

I have some Iterator

```
val i: Iterator[String] = //..
```

which is iterating through very large amount of `String`s. So its not possible to load all it's content in memory. I need to produce `Iterator[String]` which inserts separator (say `"separator"`) between each element of the source iterator. Examples

```
["1", "2", "3"] --> ["1", "separator", "2", "separator", "3"]
["1", "2"] --> ["1", "separator", "2"]
["1"] --> ["1"]
[] --> ["1"]
```

I found a solution with mutable variables:

```
class SeparatedIterator(i: Iterator[String]) extends Iterator[String] {
    private var pointToElement = false

    override def hasNext: Boolean =
      if (pointToElement && i.hasNext) true
      else i.hasNext

    override def next(): String =
      if(pointToElement && i.hasNext) {
        pointToElement = false
        "separator"
      }
      else if (i.hasNext) {
        pointToElement = true
        i.next()
      } else throw new NoSuchElementException
  }
```

Is there a functional way to do this? Without mutable variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` on the input iterator to replace each element with the element, followed by the separator. To avoid the final separator at the end, you can add an `if` that checks whether there are still elements in the iterator:

```
def separatedIterator(iter: Iterator[String]): Iterator[String] = {
    iter.flatMap { x =>
        if (iter.hasNext) Iterator(x, "separator")
        else Iterator(x)
    }
}
```

Or, as per Karl Bielefeldt's suggestion, you can put the separator first and then use `drop` to get rid of it instead of the `if`:

```
def separatedIterator(iter: Iterator[String]): Iterator[String] = {
    iter.flatMap { x => Iterator("separator", x) }.drop(1)
}
```

Comment: If you put the separator first, you can do `iter flatMap {"separator" :: _ :: Nil} drop 1` to remove the first separator.

Comment: @St.Antario, `drop` works because in Scala it is safe by design. According to the doc it "_Advances this iterator past the first ''n'' elements, or the length of the iterator, **whichever is smaller**._"